# Where to after bootstrap and Angular Material

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, material-design, angular-material

Is there a UI framework or library that is as comprehensive as Twitter Bootstrap, uses Material Design, and is a good fit with AngularJS?

I have used Twitter Bootstrap for a few years.  Recently I have started developing in AngularJS and have been trialing Angular Material.

I really like the overall look and feel of Angular Material and the way it uses flexbox.  My design skills are limited though, so I really need a comprehensive solution and I find that Angular is just not comprehensive enough (yet).

By way of example, the kinds of things that are available in Bootstrap but not Angular Material include:

- Typography: Definition lists, address formatting, inline forms
- Components: Jumbotron, page header, panels

I realize that Angular Material has similar things in some areas, but they seem to be quite specialized.  For example, you could say that Angular Material cards are akin to Bootstrap Panels, but as far as I can see there's no real point in having a card that doesn't have an image header.

Should I be looking at Polymer?  Or something else?  Bootstrap 4 looks promising, but I need something now.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has been already 'angularized': https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ . You can now use the framework you are comfortable with together with angular.

Comment: Hi, while I appreciate the efforts of the Angular-UI team, I have more confidence in either MDL or Polymer.  For example, the link you give above does not render correctly in my browser.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what does not render correctly and what is your browser ?

Answer (score 0):

Splitting your requirements: "UI framework or library that is as comprehensive as Twitter Bootstrap, uses Material Design, and is a good fit with AngularJS"

UI framework or library that is as comprehensive as Twitter Bootstrap:

Twitter Bootstrap.

Uses Material Design:

Twitter Bootstrap + [Bootstrap material design theme](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/).

Is a good fit with AngularJS:

Twitter Bootstrap + [Bootstrap material design theme](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) + [Angular Bootstrap Material](http://tilwinjoy.github.io/angular-bootstrap-material/)

<sub>Disclaimer: I wrote the last component, [Angular Bootstrap Material](http://tilwinjoy.github.io/angular-bootstrap-material/)</sub>